# Reference - What does this regex mean?

Tags: regex

### What is this?

This is a collection of common Q&A. This is also a Community Wiki, so everyone is invited to participate in maintaining it.

### Why is this?

[regex](/questions/tagged/regex) is suffering from *give me ze code* type of questions and poor answers with no explanation. This reference is meant to provide links to quality Q&A.

### What's the scope?

This reference is meant for the following languages: [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [.net](/questions/tagged/.net).

This might be too broad, but these languages share the same syntax. For specific features there's the tag of the language behind it, example:

- What are regular expression Balancing Groups? [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)

Comment: [**I created a meta discussion, everyone is invited >>>**](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228822/regex-reference-and-its-fate)

Answer (score 1211, accepted):

### The Stack Overflow Regular Expressions FAQ

See also a lot of general hints and useful links at the [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) [**tag details page**](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).

---

**Online tutorials**

- [RegexOne ↪](https://regexone.com/)
- [Regular Expressions Info ↪](https://www.regular-expressions.info/)

**Quantifiers**

- Zero-or-more: [`*`: greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), [`*?`: reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976), [`*+`: possessive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17064242)
- One-or-more: [`+`: greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10764399), [`+?`: reluctant](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7124976), [`++`: possessive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4489551)
- Zero-or-one: [`?`: greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17400486), `??`: reluctant, `?+`: possessive
- Min/max ranges (all inclusive): [`{n,m}`: between n & m](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17032985), [`{n,}`: n-or-more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17120435), [`{n}`: exactly n](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17829727)
- Differences between greedy, reluctant (a.k.a. "lazy", "ungreedy") and possessive quantifier:

  - [Greedy vs. Reluctant vs. Possessive Quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5319840)
  - [In-depth discussion on the differences between greedy versus non-greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3075532)
  - [What's the difference between `{n}` and `{n}?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18006093)
  - [Can someone explain Possessive Quantifiers to me?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1117467) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)
  - [Emulating possessive quantifiers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5537513) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
  - Non-Stack Overflow references: From [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/quant.html), [regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html)

**Character Classes**

- [What is the difference between square brackets and parentheses?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9801630)
- [`[...]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1553171): any one character, [`[^...]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20802463): negated/any character but
- [`[^]` matches any one character *including* newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25950433) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
- [`[\w-[\d]]` / `[a-z-[qz]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10738860): set subtraction [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [xml-schema](/questions/tagged/xml-schema), [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath), JGSoft
- [`[\w&&[^\d]]`: set intersection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15935168) [java](/questions/tagged/java), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) 1.9+, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) (with `v` flag)
- [`[[:alpha:]]`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12276342):POSIX character classes
- `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]` Word boundaries
- [Why do `[^\\D2]`, `[^[^0-9]2]`, `[^2[^0-9]]` get different results in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21934168) [java](/questions/tagged/java)
- Shorthand:

  - Digit: [`\d`:digit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16621778), [`\D`:non-digit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011185)
  - Word character (Letter, digit, underscore): [`\w`:word character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11874899), [`\W`:non-word character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011185)
  - Whitespace: [`\s`:whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21067350), [`\S`:non-whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19011185)
- [Unicode categories (`\p{L}, \P{L}`, etc.)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969440/what-is-the-l-unicode-category)

**Escape Sequences**

- Horizontal whitespace: [`\h`:space-or-tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4910093), [`\t`:tab](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17950891)
- Newlines:

  - [`\r`, `\n`:carriage return and line feed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3451192)
  - [`\R`:generic newline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18992691) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)
- Negated whitespace sequences: [`\H`:Non horizontal whitespace character, `\V`:Non vertical whitespace character, `\N`:Non line feed character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26972688) [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) [php5](/questions/tagged/php5) [java-8](/questions/tagged/java-8)
- Other: [`\v`:vertical tab](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12290224), [`\e`:the escape character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4275788)

**Anchors**

| anchor | matches | flavors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `^` | Start of string | Common* |
| `^` | Start of line | Common<sup>`m`</sup> |
| `$` | End of line | Common<sup>`m`</sup> |
| `$` | End of text | Common* except [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) |
| `$` | Very end of string | [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)*, [php](/questions/tagged/php)<sup>`D`</sup> |
| `\A` | Start of string | Common except [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) |
| `\Z` | End of text | Common except [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [python](/questions/tagged/python) |
| `\Z` | Very end of string | [python](/questions/tagged/python) |
| `\z` | Very end of string | Common except [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [python](/questions/tagged/python) |
| `\b` | Word boundary | Common |
| `\B` | Not a word boundary | Common |
| `\G` | End of previous match | Common except [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](/questions/tagged/python) |

| Term | Definition |
| --- | --- |
| [Start of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908745) | At the very start of the string. |
| [Start of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908745) | At the very start of the string, and after a non-terminal line terminator. |
| [Very end of string](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48832215) | At the very end of the string. |
| [End of text](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4020821) | At the very end of the string, and at a terminal line terminator. |
| [End of line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6908745) | At the very end of the string, and at a line terminator. |
| [Word boundary](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6664167) | At a word character not preceded by a word character, and at a non-word character not preceded by a non-word character. |
| [End of previous match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21971701) | At a previously set position, usually where a previous match ended. At the very start of the string if no position was set. |

"Common" refers to the following: [icu](/questions/tagged/icu) [java](/questions/tagged/java) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [swift](/questions/tagged/swift) [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)

* Default [|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D41QM.png)
<sup>`m`</sup> Multi-line mode. [|](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D41QM.png)
<sup>`D`</sup> Dollar end only mode.

**Groups**

- [`(...)`:capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127), [`(?:)`:non-capture group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3512471)

  - [How to capture multiple repeated groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37003623)
  - [Why is my repeating capturing group only capturing the last match?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23062553)
- [`\1`:backreference and capture-group reference, `$1`:capture group reference](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21880127)

  - [What's the meaning of a number after a backslash in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8624345)
  - [`\g<1>123`:How to follow a numbered capture group, such as `\1`, with a number?:](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5984633) [python](/questions/tagged/python)
- [What does a subpattern `(?i:regex)` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812728)
- [What does the 'P' in `(?P<group_name>regexp)` mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10059673/named-regular-expression-group-pgroup-nameregexp-what-does-p-stand-for)
- [`(?>)`:atomic group](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14411818) or [independent group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50524/what-is-a-regex-independent-capturing-group),  [`(?|)`:branch reset](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5333645)

  - [Equivalent of branch reset in .NET/C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5378077) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
- Named capture groups:

  - [General named capturing group reference at `regular-expressions.info`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/named.html)
  - [java](/questions/tagged/java): `(?<groupname>regex)`: [Overview](https://blogs.oracle.com/xuemingshen/entry/named_capturing_group_in_jdk7) and [naming rules](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#groupname) *(Non-Stack Overflow links)*
  - Other languages: [`(?P<groupname>regex)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10059673) [python](/questions/tagged/python), [`(?<groupname>regex)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20355718) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net), [`(?<groupname>regex)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288989) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), `(?P<groupname>regex)` and `(?<groupname>regex)` [php](/questions/tagged/php)
- [`(?<-foo>)`: balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17003799) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)

**Lookarounds**

- Lookaheads: [`(?=...)`:positive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1570916), [`(?!...)`:negative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12210820)
- Lookbehinds: [`(?<=...)`:positive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672), [`(?<!...)`:negative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197672)
- Lookbehind limits in:

  - [Lookbehinds need to be constant-length](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22821726) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby)
  - [Lookarounds of limited length `{0,n}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994257) [java](/questions/tagged/java)
  - [Variable length lookbehinds are allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20994257) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
- Lookbehind alternatives:

  - [Using `\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640500) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) ([Flavors that support `\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042))
  - [Alternative regex module for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11641102) [python](/questions/tagged/python)

    - [The hacky way](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11640862)
    - [JavaScript negative lookbehind equivalents](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35143111) <sup>[External link](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript)</sup>
- [Tempered greedy token](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30900794)

**Modifiers**

| flag | modifier | flavors |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `a` | [ASCII](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61203075) | [python](/questions/tagged/python) |
| `c` | [current position](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11395687) | [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) |
| `e` | [expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2468483) | [php](/questions/tagged/php) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) |
| `g` | [global](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9622110) | most |
| `i` | [case-insensitive](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12411066) | most |
| `m` | [multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22438123) | [php](/questions/tagged/php) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [python](/questions/tagged/python) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) [java](/questions/tagged/java) |
| `m` | [(non)multiline](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257912) | [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) |
| `o` | [once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13334823) | [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) |
| `r` | [non-destructive](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75503032) | [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) |
| `S` | [study](https://stackoverflow.com/a/210027) | [php](/questions/tagged/php) |
| `s` | [single line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594017) | [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) |
| `U` | [ungreedy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5978385) | [php](/questions/tagged/php) [r](/questions/tagged/r) |
| `u` | [unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2553239) | most |
| `x` | [whitespace-extended](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2710390) | most |
| `y` | [sticky ↪](https://javascript.info/regexp-sticky) | [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) |

- [How to convert preg_replace e to preg_replace_callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16367404)
- [What are inline modifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43636)
- [What is '?-mix' in a Ruby Regular Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630936/what-is-mix-in-a-ruby-regular-expression)
- [What does the caret `^` in `(?^:…)` mean in the string form of a Perl qr// Regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43902898)

**Other:**

- [`|`:alternation (OR) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6279354), [`.`:any character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13594017), [`[.]`:literal dot character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21929764)
- [What special characters must be escaped?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399078)
- Control verbs ([php](/questions/tagged/php) and [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)): [`(*PRUNE)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008790), [`(*SKIP)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008790), [`(*FAIL)` and `(*F)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20008790)

  - [php](/questions/tagged/php) only: [`(*BSR_ANYCRLF)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374702)
  - [The `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` idiom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24535912)
- Recursion ([php](/questions/tagged/php) and [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)): [`(?R)`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8440911), [`(?0)` and `(?1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20569361), [`(?-1)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845034), [`(?&groupname)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18151617)

**Common Tasks**

- [Get a string between two curly braces: `{...}`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/413077)
- [Match (or replace) a pattern except in situations s1, s2, s3...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
- [Find all YouTube video ids in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5830387)
- [Ignore middle part of a match](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7768321)
- Validation:

  - Internet: [email addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/201323), [URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/190405) (host/port: [regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22697740) and [non-regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24399003) alternatives), [passwords](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3802238)
  - Numeric: [a number](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4247184), [min-max ranges (such as 1-31)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22131040), [phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/123559), [date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15491894)
  - *Parsing HTML with regex: See "General Information > When not to use Regex"*

**Advanced Regex-Fu**

- Strings and numbers:

  - [Regular expression to match a line that doesn't contain a word](https://stackoverflow.com/q/406230)
  - [How does this PCRE pattern detect palindromes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3746487)
  - [Match strings whose length is a fourth power](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/19262)
  - [How does this regex find triangular numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3627681)
  - [How to determine if a number is a prime with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2795065)
  - [How to match the middle character in a string with regex?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28051651)
- Other:

  - [How can we match a^n b^n?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3644266)
  - Match nested brackets

    - [Using a recursive pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17845034) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)
    - [Using balancing groups](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
  - [“Vertical” regex matching in an ASCII “image”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17039670)
  - [List of highly up-voted regex questions on Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regular-expression?sort=votes&pageSize=50)
  - [How to make two quantifiers repeat the same number of times?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23001137)
  - [An impossible-to-match regular expression: `(?!a)a`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1723182)
  - [Match/delete/replace `this` except in contexts A, B and C](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23589174)
  - [Match nested brackets with regex without using recursion or balancing groups?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47162099)
  - [Can a Regex Return the Number of the Line where the Match is Found?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23727476)
  - [Matching overlapping strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20837608)

    - [Manually modify the `.lastIndex` property](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33903830) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
    - [With the third-party library `regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18966891) [python](/questions/tagged/python)
  - [Match a sequence of two distinct characters where the disparity in count is not greater than 3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77627009)

**Flavor-Specific Information**

*(Except for those marked with `*`, this section contains non-Stack Overflow links.)*

- Java

  - Official documentation: [Pattern Javadoc ↪](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html), [Oracle's regular expressions tutorial ↪](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/index.html)
  - The differences between functions in [`java.util.regex.Matcher`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html):

    - [`matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches--)): The match must be anchored to both input-start and -end
    - [`find()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find--)): A match may be anywhere in the input string (substrings)
    - [`lookingAt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#lookingAt--): The match must be anchored to input-start only
    - *(For anchors in general, see the section "Anchors")*
  - The only [`java.lang.String`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) functions that accept regular expressions: [`matches(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-), [`replaceAll(s,s)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [`replaceFirst(s,s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [`split(s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-), [`split(s,i)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)
  - *[An (opinionated and) detailed discussion of the disadvantages of and missing features in `java.util.regex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771326)
- .NET

  - [How to read a .NET regex with look-ahead, look-behind, capturing groups and back-references mixed together?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36047988)
- Official documentation:

  - Boost regex engine: [General syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5771326), [Perl syntax](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/syntax.html) *(used by TextPad, Sublime Text, UltraEdit, ...???)*
  - JavaScript [general info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and [RegExp object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)
  - [.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx) [image] [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html) [image] [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) [image] [Perl5 version 18.2](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)
  - PHP: [pattern syntax](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php), [`preg_match`](https://us2.php.net/preg_match)
  - Python: [Regular expression operations](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html), [`search` vs `match`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#search-vs-match), [how-to](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html)
  - Rust: [crate `regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest), [struct `regex::Regex`](https://docs.rs/regex/latest/regex/struct.Regex.html)
  - Splunk: [regex terminology and syntax](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/Knowledge/AboutSplunkregularexpressions#Terminology_and_syntax) and [regex command](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/latest/SearchReference/Regex)
  - Tcl: [regex syntax](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm), [manpage](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/regexp.htm), [`regexp` command](http://wiki.tcl.tk/986)
  - [Visual Studio Find and Replace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx)

**General information**

*(Links marked with `*` are non-Stack Overflow links.)*

- Other general documentation resources: [Learning Regular Expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4736), *[Regular-expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info), *[Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), *[RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com/), [Open-Directory Project](http://www.dmoz.org/Computers/Programming/Languages/Regular_Expressions)
- [DFA versus NFA](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3978438)
- [Generating Strings matching regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22115/using-regex-to-generate-strings-rather-than-match-them)
- Books: Jeffrey Friedl's *[Mastering Regular Expressions](http://regex.info/book.html)*
- When to *not* use regular expressions:

  - *[Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/)* (blog post written by [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/)'s founder)*
  - Do not use regex to parse HTML:

    - [Don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/590747). [image] [Please, just don't](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454)
    - [Well, maybe...if you're *really* determined](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4234491) (other answers in this question are also good)

**Examples of regex that can cause regex engine to fail**

- [Why does this regular expression kill the Java regex engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/288800/why-does-this-regular-expression-kill-the-java-regex-engine)

**Tools: Testers and Explainers**

*(This section contains non-Stack Overflow links.)*

- Online *(* includes replacement tester, + includes split tester)*:

  - [Debuggex](https://debuggex.com) (Also has a repository of useful regexes) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre)
  - *[Regular Expressions 101](https://regex101.com) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre), [python](/questions/tagged/python), [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [java](/questions/tagged/java), [go](/questions/tagged/go), [c#](/questions/tagged/c%23), [rust](/questions/tagged/rust)
  - [Regex Pal](https://regexpal.com), *[regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html)* [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
  - [Rubular](http://rubular.com/) [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby) [image] [RegExr](http://www.regexr.com/)  [image] [Regex Hero](http://regexhero.net/tester) [dotnet](/questions/tagged/dotnet)
  - *+ [regexstorm.net](http://regexstorm.net/tester) [.net](/questions/tagged/.net)
  - *RegexPlanet: [Java](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) [java](/questions/tagged/java), [Go](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/golang/index.html) [go](/questions/tagged/go), [Haskell](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/haskell/index.html) [haskell](/questions/tagged/haskell), [JavaScript](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/javascript/index.html) [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript), [.NET](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/dotnet/index.html) [dotnet](/questions/tagged/dotnet), [Perl](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/perl/index.html) [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) [php](/questions/tagged/php) [PCRE](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/php/index.html) [php](/questions/tagged/php), [Python](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/python/index.html) [python](/questions/tagged/python), [Ruby](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/ruby/index.html) [ruby](/questions/tagged/ruby), [XRegExp](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/xregexp/index.html) [xregexp](/questions/tagged/xregexp)
  - [`freeformatter.com`](http://www.freeformatter.com/regex-tester.html) [xregexp](/questions/tagged/xregexp)
  - *+[`regex.larsolavtorvik.com`](http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/) [php](/questions/tagged/php) PCRE and POSIX, [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)
- Offline:

  - Microsoft Windows: [RegexBuddy](http://regexbuddy.com) (analysis), [RegexMagic](http://regexmagic.com) (creation), [Expresso](http://www.ultrapico.com/expresso.htm) (analysis, creation, free)
- MySQL 8.0:  Various syntax changes were made.  Note especially the doubling of backslashes in some contexts.  (This Answer need further editing to reflect the differences.)

Comment: Related: [the question for which an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454) starts with *"You can't parse [X]HTML with regex."*.

Comment: Perl has more (`(?(` for conditional, for example) but you can read the perl official documentation instead.

Comment: Looks like `Refiddle` under the Tools section now points to some online casino site. Probably should be removed.

Comment: I think the anchors section is incorrect for [tag:ruby], as per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4257912/589924)